# switch port based on ip address bash script

Tags: bash

how would i switch port based on ip address in a bash script?

I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=(***.**.**.24 ***.**.**.66 ***.**.**.59 ***.**.**.67 ***.**.**.58 ***.**.**.70 ***.**.**.68)

case "$servers" in
    ***.**.**.24)
    port=28260
    ;;
    ***.**.**.58)
    port=27260
    ;;
    ***.**.**.59)
    port=27260
    ;;
    ***.**.**.66)
    port=28270
    ;;
    ***.**.**.67)
    port=27290
    ;;
    ***.**.**.68)
    port=28260
    ;;
    ***.**.**.70)
    port=28260
    ;;
esac
```

But it is returning only the first port.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: try using `?` instead of `*` for `***.**.**.24`.  Remember that case statements support [`glob`-syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob); not regex.

Comment: why does `servers` contain `***.**.**.24 ....`?  What are you trying to accomplish with that variable?

Comment: Hmm, i have * instead of the full ip, sorry for not explaining.

Comment: Here's the full script for others that might be interested: https://gist.github.com/tmiland/10823685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `servers` is an array of multiple elements, while `$servers` just expands to the first one.

If you want to loop through the array and print something for each of the entries, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash     
servers=(***.**.**.24 ***.**.**.66 ***.**.**.59 ***.**.**.67 ***.**.**.58 ***.**.**.70 ***.**.**.68)

for host in "${servers[@]}"
do
  case "$host" in
      ***.**.**.24)
      port=28260
      ;;
      ***.**.**.58)
      port=27260
      ;;
      ***.**.**.59)
      port=27260
      ;;
      ***.**.**.66)
      port=28270
      ;;
      ***.**.**.67)
      port=27290
      ;;
      ***.**.**.68)
      port=28260
      ;;
      ***.**.**.70)
      port=28260
      ;;
  esac

  echo "$host:$port"
done
```